# Zend storing data in session

Tags: php, session, zend-framework

I'm new in Zend and php. For a project, i need to gather 3 ajax Zend Forms together. I know i need to use session to do that but i can't find any information about how to do that. Can someone help me ?

EDIT :

```
    public function formResAction(){

        $form = new Front_Form_ResPhone();
        $bdd_Reservation = new Front_Model_DbTable_Reservation();

        if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
            if($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())){
                // Données non valides

                $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('forms');
                $formData = $form->getValues();
                $session->form1 = $formData;
                print_r ($session->form1);

                echo $this->view->bloc11Fid($formData);
                exit;
            }
            else{
                // Données non valides
//              echo "non valide";
            }
        }
        else{
            // Appel en GET
//              echo "GET";
        }
        echo $form;
        exit;

}

    public function formFidAction(){

            $form = new Front_Form_FidForm();
            $bdd_Reservation = new Front_Model_DbTable_Reservation();

        if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
            if($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())){
                // Données non valides

                $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('forms');
                $formData = $form->getValues();
                $session->form2 = $formData;
                print_r ($session->form2);

                echo $this->view->bloc11Fid2($formData);
                exit;
            }
            else{
                // Données non valides
//              echo "non valide";
            }
        }
        else{
            // Appel en GET
//              echo "GET";
        }
        echo $form;
        exit;

}

    public function formFid2Action(){

            $form = new Front_Form_FidForm2();
            $bdd_Reservation = new Front_Model_DbTable_Reservation();

        if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
            if($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())){
                // Données non valides

                $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('forms');
                $formData = $form->getValues();
                $session->form3 = $formData;
                print_r ($session->form3);  

                echo $this->view->bloc11Res($formData);

                exit;
            }
            else{
                // Données non valides
//              echo "non valide";
            }
        }
        else{
            // Appel en GET
//              echo "GET";
        }
        echo $form;
        exit;

}

public function resFormAction(){

        $form = new Front_Form_ResForm();
        $bdd_Reservation = new Front_Model_DbTable_Reservation();

        if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
            if($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())){
                // Données non valides

                $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('forms');
                $formData = $form->getValues();
                $session->form4 = $formData;
                print_r ($session);

                $bdd_Reservation->insert($forms);

                echo $this->view->bloc11Fel($formData);
                exit;


                exit;
            }
            else{
                // Données non valides
//              echo "non valide";
            }
        }
        else{
            // Appel en GET
//              echo "GET";
        }
        echo $form;
        exit;       
}
```

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.form.advanced.html#zend.form.advanced.multiPage

Comment: there is no easier synthax ? I don't understand that documentation :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this:

```
//create a session namespace
$session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('myapp');

$session->somevar = 'somevalue';

echo $session->somevar; //somevalue
```

**Zend_Session_Namespace** has magic getter and setter.

So, if a attribute of the session object is not set, it will be **NULL** by default.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.session.basic_usage.html

Comment: thanks ! there is no key to define new Session ? like : $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('myapp', $somevar); ?

Comment: You can use the session namespace "myform" and then use a var for your form parameter array.

Comment: Like 
$session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('mywizard');
$formname = 'wizard1';
$session->{$formname} = $form->getParams();

Comment: Check isset($session->{$formname}) and validate like $form->isValid($session->{$formname})!

Comment: I didn't understand how to use the setter and the getter.. Do you have an exemple ? I don't understand the documentation

Comment: I mean, you just use the attribs as if they would exist in the class.

What you want to achieve is storing the form params in the session, identified by some unique key.

The unique key is eg the id of the form.

So you have this Namespace $session = Zend_Session_Namespace('Form_Wizard'), now add your form params to an attribute of your newly create Zend_Session_Namespace Object.

Comment: Maybe validate the params first, then store to the session to use it later.

So, first $form->isValid($post), then $session->form1 = $post_params and after that redirect with next page of your wizard active.

You can check if a step is solved by just checking for existence of this form's id in the session namespace.